# Help with finding a matrix given a subspace V

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with solving this question. I understand how to get a basis for the null space and the column space, but I don't know how to create a matrix with what I've been given.

I need to create a matrix A with null space V and create a matrix D with column space V. How do I go about doing that.

It's my first time posting so any help is appreciated

The question is as follows:

Let V be the subspace of all vectors in $R^6$, such that:

$$x_1+x_3=x_2+x_4=x_5-x_6$$

1)Find a matrix A with V as its null space, so $V= Nul A$. What is the rank of A?

2)Find a matrix D with V as its column space, so $V= Col D$. Explain why the equality $V= Col D$ holds.

Here's a photo for reference

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs2Iz.jpg

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you! I have added the question.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ -1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ -1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
is a set of basic vectors for $V$. Question 2 now is very easy to answer as we can just take 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
and we easily find that $\text{span}(B)$ is the column space of $A$.

To find a matrix for which $V$ is the null space, we just have to extend $B$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{6}$ with vectors orthogonal to $V$. So we need vectors
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\ x_{3}\\ x_{4}\\ x_{5}\\ x_{6}\end{pmatrix}$$
such that $x_{1}-x_{3}=0$, $x_{2}-x_{4}=0$, $x_{5}+x_{6}=0$ and $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{5}=0$. With an educated guess we find that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ -2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix} -2\\ -2\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$
satisfy our conditions. Then 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 2\\-2 & -2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
has Null space $V$.

Comment: There’s no need to guess to solve the first part. The equations that define $V$ are equivalent to a system of homogeneous linear equations (how did you find those basis vectors in the first place?), so $V$ is exactly the null space of the system’s coefficient matrix, which one can write down directly from those defining equations.